# Apply awk function for first line alone in a file

Tags: shell, awk

I have file like below

```
#ValToCut#FilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontent
FilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontent
FilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontent
FilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontentFilecontent
```

I need to cut "#ValToCut#" this alone and save it in a variable.
Rest content should be in file itself

```
var=$(awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,1,10)}' filename)
awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,10)}' filename > filename
```

But this function gets applied for all the lines in second command.

Comment: `grep -o '^#[^#]*#' filename > newfilename`?

Comment: This #ValToCut# value will be dynamic. I can apply by lenght alone

Comment: Ok, then `awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,1,10)}'` already yields `#ValToCut#`

Comment: If you need to remove the value from file afterwards, use `sed`: `sed -i '1 s/^.\{10\}//' file`

Comment: In `awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,10)}' filename > filename` you use the same niput and output filename. That should be avoided. Test it with another output filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a command line:

```
var=$( awk '(NR==1){ match($0,/#[^#]*#/;
                    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
                    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                   }
            {print > "newfile"}' file)
```

This will have stored that section in variable `var` and moved all the other lines to `newfile`. The first line will have `var` removed from it.